# onPostExecute() does not execute after doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this code

```
public class AsyncClassTest extends Activity {

String strMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new MyClass().execute();

    Toast.makeText(AsyncClassTest.this, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

}

public class MyClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return "Hello world!!!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        strMessage = result;
    }
}
```

}

and when is runs, after `new MyClass().execute();` it shows that `strMessage` is null and after showing toast code goes in `onPostExecute()` method, how to make this code run and show the message after `new MyClass().execute();`

Comment: Show the Toast in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: oh, everybody wrote same answer..:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(AsyncClassTest.this, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();
```

Remove it form `onCreate` and write it in `onPostExecute`

In you code that Toast execute before your `AsyncTask` come in Action , always remember that `AsyncTask` is a background `thread` .

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AsyncClassTest extends Activity {

String strMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new MyClass().execute();

}

public class MyClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        return "Hello world!!!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        strMessage = result;
        Toast.makeText(AsyncClassTest.this, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the value of the string in an `AsyncTask`. When you call execute(), it will run asynchronously(a separate Thread) and the Toast will, in all likelihood, be shown before the value of the string is set.

Basically, execute() does not "wait" for `onPostExecute` to be called. It spawns a separate Thread and your `onCreate()` method moves on to show the Toast with the old value.

Try moving the `Toast.makeText` into the `onPostExecute` Command to see it work.

Also, if you really wanted `onPostExecute` to finish executing before you moved on to the Toast. You really shouldn't be using an `AsyncTask` for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        strMessage = result;

 Toast.makeText(AsyncClassTest.this, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    }
```

`onPostExecute(Result)`, invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, `AsyncTask` is something that runs asynchronously, so you can't just `execute()` it and expect that it returns before the next line of code gets called. So you should create the `Toast` inside `onPostExecute()` (or inside a method that gets called in `onPostExecute()`), as when the `onPostExecute()` gets called you know for sure that the task has finished.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` is, as the name may suggest, asynchronous. that means that it is not necessarly executed before the next line

If you have an operation to do *after* the task is complete, it must be done or started in `onPostExecute`